# Chosen select width problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-chosen

I am using the chosen select plugin in a bootstrap site and in a table. My problem is, as u can see on the picture, the width will be bigger in each row.[image]

The bootstrap and the chosen css is the basis.

The generated html in the page source:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered list"><thead style="font-weight:bold;">
                                  <tr class="tr_bold">
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
                                    <td class="left">Megnevezés</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Egység</td>
                                    <td>Bruttó ár</td>
                                    <td>Akciós ár</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Akciós</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead><tbody>                             <tr id="sor52">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="52" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">52</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=52">Barabás Gerecse térkő őszilomb</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[52]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[52]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[52]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor117">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="117" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">117</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=117">Barabás Patent térkő 222</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[117]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[117]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[117]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor50">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="50" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=50">Barabás Somló Trió térkő holdfény</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[50]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[50]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[50]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

Edit:

If i delete the form-control class from the select, it will be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
select {
  width: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered list"><thead style="font-weight:bold;">
                                  <tr class="tr_bold">
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
                                    <td class="left">Megnevezés</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Egység</td>
                                    <td>Bruttó ár</td>
                                    <td>Akciós ár</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Akciós</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead><tbody>                             <tr id="sor52">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="52" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">52</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=52">Barabás Gerecse térkő őszilomb</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[52]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[52]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[52]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor117">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="117" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">117</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=117">Barabás Patent térkő 222</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[117]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[117]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[117]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor50">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="50" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=50">Barabás Somló Trió térkő holdfény</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[50]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[50]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[50]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution**

- Remove style="text-align:center" from last td. Because, inside 
  that td, any element can be center.
  Also add css to your stylesheet from below code snippet.

```css
.input-select{
  width:100% !Important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered list"><thead style="font-weight:bold;">
                                  <tr class="tr_bold">
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
                                    <td class="left">Megnevezés</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Egység</td>
                                    <td>Bruttó ár</td>
                                    <td>Akciós ár</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">Akciós</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead><tbody>                             <tr id="sor52">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="52" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">52</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=52">Barabás Gerecse térkő őszilomb</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[52]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[52]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[52]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor117">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="117" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">117</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=117">Barabás Patent térkő 222</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[117]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[117]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[117]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                                            <tr id="sor50">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sav_id[]" class="sav_input" value="50" />
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
                                    <td class="left"><a title="Megnyitás" style="color:#333;" target="_blank" href="https://projektar.hu/cms2/termek-szerkesztes.php?id=50">Barabás Somló Trió térkő holdfény</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">m2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="a[50]" value="1000" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="b[50]" value="500" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <td >
                                        <select name="termek_akcio[50]" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  selected="selected" value="1">Igen</option><option  value="0">Nem</option>                                     </select>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

Comment: I did, what you say, but still the same problems.

Comment: add in code snippet then only I can check. Or It may be some other css is overriding.

Comment: I cant, because its to much css. Chat?

Comment: @Webshop2229 I updated answer olease check codesnipet now.